# Upper bound for coefficients of $\Phi_{pqr} (x)$

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, cyclotomic-polynomials

At the end of a [Monthly note](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2313416.pdf?ab_segments=0%2Fbasic_SYC-5187%2Fcontrol&refreqid=fastly-default%3A8c44034f0e13ead94747035d4f5c2ce7), Beiter conjectured the following.

> Let $p<q<r$ be primes greater than $3$. Writing the $pqr$-th cyclotomic polynomial as
> $$\Phi_{pqr} (x)= \sum c_nx^n$$
> With $c_{\phi(pqr)}=1$, we have $|c_n| \leq \frac 12 (p+1)$ for all primes $q,r$.

Actually, he conjectures $\frac 12(p+1)$ is an upper bound for $c_n$, but I believe he meant $|c_n|$.

This note was published in 1968. Has this conjecture been settled/has there been analysis on the coefficients of $\Phi_n$ for squarefree $n$ with exactly three factors?

Comment: I also think he means $|c_n|$ , I see no reason why the absolute value should only be bounded for the positive coefficients. Upto which limit has this been approved ?